# How to set table column footer to the bottom of the detail band?

Tags: jasper-reports, table-footer

I'm using table in jasperreport and I need to add table column footer to the bottom just before "group footer" band like

[image: here]

But currently it generates table like here

[image: this]

as you can see a lot of spaces between the table (which in detail band) and group footer band..

```
<detail>
    <band height="80">
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement key="table1" style="tableStyle" x="1" y="0" width="552" height="80" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="9a24d27b-9228-4f23-8c02-628268479882">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT} == 1]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail">
                <datasetRun subDataset="TableDataset" uuid="aad66998-86ba-485c-b8f4-3f2f6eda4796">
                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{datasourceItems}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                </datasetRun>
                <jr:column width="25" uuid="eb2f74b3-8006-4762-a52e-838f5e08a86f">
                    <jr:columnHeader height="40" rowSpan="2">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement style="tableProduct_CH" x="0" y="0" width="25" height="40" uuid="6ce8147d-c282-467a-b348-0d5cf3def735"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[No]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:columnFooter style="tableProductFooterNoLine" height="20" rowSpan="1"/>
                    <jr:detailCell height="20" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                            <reportElement style="tableProduct_TD" x="0" y="0" width="25" height="20" uuid="fc581740-46a3-4602-b769-18beca53d355"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{no}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column> ...
            </jr:table>
        </componentElement>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFIK: This is **not** possible in jasper reports version <=6.7 (current version at date of answer) using the `jr:table` component.

You could draw the lines in the `background` band and then add the footer for example in a `groupFooter` band, but I would instead suggest that you create a subreport to avoid problems with page break.

The subreport will mimic the table using the standard `detail` and `columnFooter` band, again you will be adding the vertical lines in the `background` band.

How the `columnFooter` will behave is define by the attribute [`isFloatColumnFooter`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRReport.html#isFloatColumnFooter) hence in your case `false`